# Starting with forward slashes link href does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css

i use Admin LTE template for my project. In this template js and css files download with follow codes:

```
<link href="//code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/1.5.2/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

But browser can't download this link. How i can configure the option so its automaticly download the URLs ?

Not: i can't refactor template's codes.

Answer (score 0):

That is a protocol-less url and will only work if your set up your project in a local web server. You can use any open-source web-server there are a lot of them.

So, all you've to make sure that you're on a correct protocol, because as of now, it is searching in `file://` protocol, which is in turn, the local file system of your computer.

Answer (score 0):

That URL resolves successfully relative to any `http://` or `https://` URL. Make sure that the document you are accessing it from is served over one of those protocols.

It will not work for `file://` URLs.

If you are doing local development, to install a local webserver. There are many things browsers do differently with deprived of HTTP (resolving scheme relative URIs and handling permissions for Ajax are two of the main ones).